# Excel VBA delete empty cells and move contents up

Tags: vba, excel

I have data like this:

```
     xxxxx
xxxxx
     xxxxx
xxxxx
     xxxxx
xxxxx         
     xxxxx
xxxxx
```

I want to write a macro to go through each column from top to bottom, cut and paste the cells up. Here's my code working with the second column.

```
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
x = 1
For y = 1 To 75
    If Cells(y, 2).Value <> "" Then
         Cells(y, 2).Cut
            Cells(x, 2).Paste
            x = x + 1
        End If
Next y
```

Excel keeps telling me: "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the Cells(x, 2).Paste

It doesn't run at all.
Disregard the range of 75. I'm only have small data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells(x, 2).Paste` isn't a valid command. use `Cells(x, 2).PasteSpecial`

try using intellisense to guide you to valid commands.

Comment: You can also do `Cells(y, 2).Cut Destination:= Cells(x, 2)`

Comment: yeah, some time it shows the commands, most of the time it doesn't show anything although I'm typing other commands right.

Comment: @knt5784 If you always `Dim` a variable and set it equal to lets say a `Range` or something then when you put a `.` after the value the method/property window will show.